# I can not use the getline in Clion

Tags: c

`I'm trying to use the getline in the Clion IDE but I can not.
I use C language
this is the code.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>

    void ler_ficheiro(){
    // variaveis par ler o ficheiro
    FILE*   ficheiro;
    char*    linha;;
    size_t  len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    // variaveis para contar as linhas
    int n_linha;

    ficheiro = fopen( "input.txt", "r");
    n_linha = 0;

    if( !ficheiro ){
        perror("ERROR");
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        while( getline(&linha, &len, ficheiro ) != -1 ){
            char sub_linha[1000];
            strcpy(sub_linha, linha);
            colocar_buffer(sub_linha, n_linha);
            n_linha++;
        }
    }
    fclose(ficheiro);
}

    int main(){
    ler_ficheiro();
}
```

And give me this error

```
   CMakeFiles\6.dir/objects.a(work.c.obj): In function `ler_ficheiro':
C:/Users/Victor cardoso/Desktop/6/work.c:128: undefined reference to `getline'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\6.dir\build.make:96: 6.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:67: CMakeFiles/6.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:79: CMakeFiles/6.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: 6] Error 2
```

Comment: post code and error in the question not in a picture....

Comment: To ask a proper question here in stackoverflow, please paste the actual complete code needed to reproduce your  problem not a link to an image of the code

Comment: Ok thats better and now please add the correct formating.

Comment: You need to link to the correct library. What you are seeing is a linker error. Since this is a typical beginner mistake I recommend that you google for the proper libraries that you need.

Answer (score 2):

You are on Windows.  `getline` is a POSIX function, not required by the C standard, and the C runtime used by your compiler (MinGW) does not implement it.  I am surprised it appears in your `stdio.h`; you should at least have gotten an "implicit function declaration" warning as well as the linker error.

I suggest using `fgets` instead, it is probably good enough for what you appear to be doing.

Comment: By the way, it is not that hard to provide an implementation of `getline` based on `fgets` and `realloc`. It can be handy when using sources from Linux

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is that you do not have the correct compile environment for using the `getline()` function.

That would explain the "undefined reference" error for `getline()` you are seeing.

The `getline()` function was a GNU extension to the Standard library.

See [getline(3) Linux Programmer's Manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) which mentions:

> ```
>        Since glibc 2.10:
>            _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L
>        Before glibc 2.10:
>            _GNU_SOURCE
> ```
>
> Both getline() and getdelim() were originally GNU extensions.  They
>          were standardized in POSIX.1-2008.

and the example provided uses:

```
   #define _GNU_SOURCE
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
```